# Show array data in Table rows in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I output that `productName` inside that `return`? The `items` are from the *selected cart items*. The `const order` (function) does show in the *console*, but I can't get it to show inside the return of render.

```
const mapState = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

const mapCartItems = createStructuredSelector({
  items: selectCartItems,
});

const CheckingOut = (product) => {
  const { total, cartCount, items } = useSelector(mapCartItems);
    const order = {
    orderItems: items.map((item) => {
      const { productName, qty} = item;
      return {
        productName,
      };
      console.log(item.productName); // this one is showing in the console
    }),
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Container fixed>
          <table >
            <tr>
              <td>Name : </td> // like show the items here
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <br></br>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <PaymentIcon
                  style={{ marginRight: "1rem", color: " #e31837" }}
                />
                Total Price:
              </td>
              <td>₱{total}.00</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        //just other codes for submit 
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckingOut;
```

Comment: @AjeetShah not yet, I could see the products in the console. The return part is still the problem

Comment: @AjeetShah i've already edited the code

Comment: @AjeetShah I'm sorry, i'm just new to SO, you mean, I should edit the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `items` is an array similar to:

```js
[
  { ID: 1, productName: 'p1', qty: 10 },
  { ID: 2, productName: 'p2', qty: 15 },
]
```

You can show `productName` and `qty` of each item in this array in `<tr>` and `<td>` of a table as:

```
{items.map((item) => (
    <tr key={item.ID}>
        <td>Name: {item.productName}</td>
        <td>{item.qty}</td>
    </tr>
))}
```

This will work even when `items` is empty array i.e. `[]`. In case, it is `null` or `undefined`, you may do [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

It will show something like this in the table at UI:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Name: p1 | 10 |
| Name: p2 | 15 |

PS: Above solution doesn't really require a separate function `order` as shown in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
const order = (product) => {
  const order = {
    orderItems: items.map((item) => {
      const { productName, qty} = item;
      return {
        productName,
      };
    }),
  };

  order.orderItems.forEach((item) => console.log(item.productName)) // will log all productName
return order.orderItems
}
```

Function `order` will return `order.orderItems` which has array of objects. For example:

```
order :{
  orderItems: [
    {
      productName: 'car',
    },
    {
      productName: 'bike',
    }
  ]
}
```

To access each of product name you have to iterate throught Array nested in `order.orderItems`

```
order(product).forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.productName) // car, bike
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map over arrays and return each element of the array inside a `jsx` element. If you had an array:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

You could map over them and return them as:

```
arr?.map(num => (<p> {num} </p>))
```

Likewise, you can do:

```
return(
  order?.orderItems?.map(item => (
    <p>{item.productName} </p>
  ))
)
```

Comment: What does the question mark mean in this context? I only know it in ternary if-else conditions.

Comment: I guess it mean `order && order.orderItems && order.orderItems.map(item => ... )`

Comment: Exactly as @Aga said. It doesn't procede if the preceding variable is *falsy*

Comment: No? `optional chaining` is its name. I described what it does.

Comment: Who are you talking to? OP?

Answer (score 1):

### EDITED

```js
// WHITHOUT STATE
const order = (product) => {
  const order = {
    orderItems: items.map((item) => {
      const { productName, qty} = item;
      return {
        productName,
      };
    })
  };
  return order; // Add this line to return your order object
};

// WITH STATE
const [myOrders, setMyOrders] = useState({});
const order = (product) => {
  setMyOrders({
    orderItems: items.map((item) => {
      const { productName, qty} = item;
      return {
        productName,
      };
    })
  });
  return //some layout;
};
```

Then in the return you can access like this:

```js
// WITHOUT STATE 
return order().orderItems.map(item =>
  whatever you want to do with item.productName...
);

// WITH STATE
return myOrders.orderItems.map(item =>
  whatever code you want to add...
);
```

Comment: what if I already have existing codes in the return?like i've got a div inside there with some layouts

Comment: Then you can `useState` to set your orders and access them easily... something like `const [myOrders, setMyOrders] = useState({});`, check in my edited answer what it would be like